# Dynamically generate method from string?

Tags: python, function, object

I have a `dict` of different types for which I want to add a simple getter based on the name of the actual parameter.

For example, for three storage parameters, let's say:

```
self.storage = {'total':100,'used':88,'free':1}
```

I am looking now for a way (if possible?) to generate a function on the fly with some meta-programming magic.

Instead of

```
class spaceObj(object):
    def getSize(what='total'):
      return storage[what]
```

or hard coding

```
@property
def getSizeTotal():
  return storage['total']
```

but

```
class spaceObj(object):
# manipulting the object's index and magic
@property
def getSize: 
    return ???
```

so that calling `mySpaceObj.getSizeFree` would be derived - with getSize only defined once in the object and related functions derived from it by manipulating the objects function list.

Is something like that possible?

Comment: How is `size` and `total` related?

Comment: I am not sure to understand the question, but you need either `getattr`, or `__getitem__`

Comment: You could do that - but what do you hope to gain over your current approach?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

While certainly possible to get an unknown attribute from a class as a property, this is not a pythonic approach (`__getattr__` magic methods are rather rubyist)

```
class spaceObj(object):
    storage = None

    def __init__(self):  # this is for testing only
        self.storage = {'total':100,'used':88,'free':1}

    def __getattr__(self, item):
        if item[:7] == 'getSize':  # check if an undefined attribute starts with this
            return self.getSize(item[7:])

    def getSize(self, what='total'):
        return self.storage[what.lower()]

print (spaceObj().getSizeTotal)  # 100
```

Comment: @Thomas "While certainly possible to get an unknown attribute from a class as a property, this is not a pythonic approach" means "although you can make idiosyncratic language syntax, everyone else is going to have a hard time making sense of it". So "works like a charm" is probably more accurately "works like a charm for me this week".

Answer (score 2):

You can put the values into the object as properties:

```
class SpaceObj(object):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        self.__dict__.update(kwargs)

storage = {'total':100,'used':88,'free':1}
o = SpaceObj(**storage)
print o.total
```

or

```
o = SpaceObj(total=100, used=88, free=1)
print o.total
```

or using `__getattr__`:

```
class SpaceObj(object):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        self.storage = kwargs

    def __getattr__(self,name):
        return self.storage[name]

o = SpaceObj(total=100, used=88, free=1)
print o.total
```

The latter approach takes a bit more code but it's more safe; if you have a method `foo` and someone create the instance with `SpaceObj(foo=1)`, then the method will be overwritten with the first approach.

Answer (score -2):

```
>>> import new
>>> funcstr = "def wat(): print \"wat\";return;"
>>> funcbin = compile(funcstr,'','exec')
>>> ns = {}
>>> exec funcbin in ns
>>> watfunction = new.function(ns["wat"].func_code,globals(),"wat")
>>> globals()["wat"]=watfunction
>>> wat()
wat
```

Comment: How does this help? (or even bear a resemblance to the question?)